# Wix Custom Action Not working in another machine

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

i have created a custom action for getting sites from IIS server.when i run it in my local machine it's working perfectly.but when i run it in another machine it's not working.

locator for custom action
<"Binary Id ="IisManager" SourceFile="$(var.SourceDir)\bin\CustomActions.CA.dll"/>
("used for foarmat this)

```
<UI Id="MyWixUI_Mondo">
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo"/>
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />

  <DialogRef Id="IisSettings" />      

  <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="IisSettings" Order="3">LicenseAccepted = "1"</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="SetupTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="IisSettings">1</Publish>


  <InstallUISequence>
    <Custom Action="GetIISWebSites" After="CostFinalize" Overridable="yes">NOT Installed</Custom>
    <Custom Action="GetIISAppPools" After="CostFinalize" Overridable="yes">NOT Installed</Custom>
  </InstallUISequence>

</UI>
```

have i done something wrong? working only in my machine...

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Are you getting any errors? If not can you paste the logs?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is that you might not have admin rights on the other machine.

Comment: this is the error i got from log file.MSI (c) (E0!30) Custom Action Exception System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(RuntimeType objectType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(RuntimeType serverType)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running Setup file with Administrative privileges resolved the issue.

CMD ->>Run As administrator -> Go To setup file and Run it.

Answer (score 1):

Your custom action is crashing because it's referencing a COM class that is not registered on the other machine. Apparently that CLSID belongs to Microsoft.ApplicationHost.WritableAdminManager and the ServerManager managed API, so if they are not present on the target machine your code will fail. A web search for -CLSID {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344- may get you some more info, but this isn't a WiX or Windows Installer issue as far as I can tell.